# Locking a table using VBA macro

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have made a table which auto fills using a user form. Currently, you can add new rows and edit the text within the table. I want to be able to lock the table so that you cannot edit the table at all unless you enter it through the user form. I tried the code:

```
Private Sub Lock_Table()
    Dim NewArea As Table
    Set NewArea = ActiveDocument.Tables(1)
    NewArea.Locked = True
End Sub
```

But that came back with the error "method or data member not found"

any help would be appreciated
Thanks!

Comment: Right, because a [`Table`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.table) does not have a `Locked` property.

Comment: Okay thank you. Do you have any recommendations???

Comment: Place the table inside a Rich Text Content Control and set the properties to prevent deletion or editing. Your code will then need to allow editing before you can apply any changes from the user form, and disallow editing again afterwards.

Comment: Okay that sounds like a good idea. I am reasonably new to VBA, so is there any chance you could help with the allowing editing as I have never done that before? edit**** You can't  add a table rich text box

Comment: You would edit the property of the CC to allow editing. Then you would need another to disallow it. You **can** put a table *inside* a rich text content control. If it is the only CC in the document the following allows editing. `activedocument.ContentControls(1).LockContentControl=False` With multiple content controls there are a number of ways to identify the one you want.

Comment: @CharlesKenyon I cannot seem to figure out how to put a table inside the rich text box. Whenever I try and copy and paste it, it disappears?

Comment: Here is a temporary link to a document containing a Rich Text CC that has a table in it. https://www.dropbox.com/s/qgk6y7slsvevsgr/deleteme.docx?dl=0 You first create the CC and then insert the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The following code will insert a table inside a new Rich Text Content Control.

```
Selection.Range.ContentControls.Add (wdContentControlRichText)
ActiveDocument.Tables.Add Range:=Selection.Range, NumRows:=2, NumColumns:= _
    2, DefaultTableBehavior:=wdWord9TableBehavior, AutoFitBehavior:= _
    wdAutoFitFixed
```

That is from a recorded macro and certainly could be improved to not use the selection object. It gives a 2x2 table inside a rich text content control.

### The following locks the first content control in a document.

```
ActiveDocument.ContentControls(1).Range _
    .LockContents = True
```

That cannot be edited. Obviously, you would change this to False before editing in your userform.

Comment: Thats Great! Thank you. I have managed to put the table in the text box, but when I try and lock it with the code you mentioned it comes up with the error: Method or data member not found.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention its the '.LockContents' that flags up as the problem

Comment: I managed to work out the problem. 'ActiveDocument.ContentControls(1).LockContents = False' seemed to work for me.